# How to encrypt a file with macros

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to encrypt a file to require other users to enter a password before opening it. If I didn't have macros in my file, this would be very easy (file, protect workbook, encrypt), but I am getting an error that I cannot do this with my macros in place. How do I go about encrypting the file (I am brand new to coding, so I also need instructions on where to place the code etc.)

I found a video that let me protect sheets, but didn't encrypt them. I also tried the code at the bottom of this link, but I was getting errors stating that various aspects of the code were not defined.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/workbook-encryption-with-macro-help/c0dd3057-7d4e-4b6a-a3c0-a2b66cd4d292

How do I accomplish this (seemingly) basic task?

Thank you!

Comment: You can definitely encrypt workbooks with macros in. `File > Protect Workbook > Encrypt with password`. If this does not work then there is either a problem with your file type (.xlsm for macros) or your file is corrupt.

Comment: Unless by "How to encrypt a file with macros" you mean "Encrypt a file, using a macro to do so"? (as opposed to "Encrypt a file that contains macros")

Comment: Encrypting a file is done with the [`Workbook.SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) method, by specifying a `Password` parameter (which you want to prompt the user for, not hard-code it anywhere). "Protecting" sheets has nothing to do with encryption. So, add a standard module to your VBA project, have a `Public Sub EncryptThisWorkbook()` procedure in it, then add some shape to your worksheet, attach the `EncryptThisWorkbook` macro to it; that's where you will want to have the `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs` member call.